# Quick Log Rule Confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I want to simplify $$\log_{c}{-c}$$

I know that $$\log_{c}{c^k} = k$$

But is there a $\log$ rule for the first one?

Comment: $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x\leq0$. This means that $c<0$. However, $x^b=-x$ only holds for $x=1$ and $x=0$, and the former case only for $b=2n$, where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Logarithms of negative numbers are undefined.

Comment: I feel so stupid after asking that question !!??!!  Haha... I totally new that :P

Comment: You shouldn't let other people define your questions.  Logarithms most certainly are definable with complex numbers involved.  Have you ever heard of $e^{\pi I}+1=0$?  It is Euler's identity.  Solve for $\pi i$ and you get a $\ln(-1)$!

Comment: Note that you can use the multiplication rule to factor negative one out of the first log.  Then you take the $log_c(-1)+1$, which requires an understanding of complex logarithms.  The solution is given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logarithms of negative numbers aren't defined on the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Note that for any positive number $c$ there is no $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $c^k=-c$. Also if you look at a graph of $y=\log x$ you can see that it's undefined for $x\leq0$.

Comment: :/  Not to be a sour loser, but I feel your answer receives more votes because people don't understand my answer.

Comment: Also, why are you assuming that the OP is defining his question to real numbers?

Comment: As the question was tagged algebra-precalculus and not complex-numbers, I assumed the OP didn't learn euler's identity yet so it would be pointless to try to define logarithms of negative numbers. I agree that your answer is correct, but if it was what OP was looking for, he can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_c(-c)=\log_c(-1*c)=\log_c(-1)+\log_c(c)=\log_c(-1)+1=\frac{\ln(-1)}{\ln(c)}+1=\frac{(2n-1)\pi i}{\ln(c)}+1$$ $$=(2n-1)\pi i\log_c(e)+1$$$$n=\pm0,\pm1,\pm2,...$$